# Return couchbase documents from keys

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I want to retrieve all documents that exist based on list collection i have using spring-data-couchbase

Currently i am using

```
public interface PushRepository extends CrudRepository<Push,String>
```

and function  `pushRepository.findAll(phoneNumbers)` but i think it is retrieving all of them and then do the filtering .

How can i run a N1QL query so i only retrieve documents on keys

```
 @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE role = 'admin' AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
 Collection<Push> findByIds();
```

The query i want to run is the below

```
select * from activation use keys ["xxxxx","yyyyy"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findAll(Iterable)` uses an underlying view (which is supposed to index only the documents that correspond to your `Push` entity) but it does provide which view keys to restrict on, so it should already be pretty efficient.

That said, if you want to do a N1QL query that directly uses document keys, that's still certainly possible with `@Query`. Since you use keys directly, there's no particular need for a WHERE clause (you know the keys correspond to `Push` documents). So you can simply do an inline query like this:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} USE KEYS [\"xxxxx\", \"yyyyy\"]")
Collection<Push> myCustomFind();
```

If you want to dynamically construct the list of keys, you'd have to look up the correct syntax but I bet this is doable using SpEL. For instance, taking two keys from the method parameters in the query signature can be done like this:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} USE KEYS [\"#{[0]}\", \"#{[1]}\"]")
Collections<Push> findTwoByN1qlKey(String key1, String key2);
```